# update-alternatives: disable log file /var/log/alternatives.log

Tags: debian, alternatives

I would like to disable the logfile `/var/log/alternatives.log`. I understand that this is being logged by `update-alternatives` script, and I also understand that `update-alternatives` can take the argument `--log`, specifying an non-standard log file (in my case I would like /dev/null). But since `update-alternatives` is run automatically, I don't know how to specify that command line option `--log`.

Is there some config file, where I could specify the `--log` parameter ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`update-alternatives` has no configuration file. If you want to effectively avoid logging, you can make `/var/log/alternatives.log` a symbolic link to `/dev/null`.

If even the existence of `/var/log/alternatives.log` is a problem, you can make a shell wrapper. Divert `update-alternatives`:

```
dpkg-divert --add --local --rename --divert /usr/bin/update-alternatives.bin /usr/bin/update-alternatives
```

Write this shell script as `/usr/bin/update-alternatives`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/update-alternatives.bin --log /dev/null "$@"
```

Comment: I have experimented with `dpkg-divert` a little and now I am not sure if i have not messed up my system. is it possible to show the current dpkg-diverts, so that i can check if everything is correct ?

Comment: @user1968963 `dpkg-divert --list`